# How to Handle BodyParser Errors (and in General Middleware errors) in NestJS

Tags: nestjs

I'm tring to handle bodyparser errors with NestJS but I can't figure out how

this is what I have done so far;

> main.ts

```
const expressServer = express.default();

const createFunction = async (expressInstance): Promise<void> => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(expressInstance), {
    cors: true,
    bodyParser: true,
  });
  app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter());
  app.use(helmet());
  await app.init();
};

createFunction(expressServer)
  .then((v) => console.log('Nest ok'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('Nest ko', err));

export const api = functions.region('europe-west3').https.onRequest(expressServer);
```

I tried to catch the error after bodyparser.

I then tried to use Filters

> app.module.ts

```
import { Module, NestModule, MiddlewareConsumer } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { APP_FILTER } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AllExceptionsFilter } from './catch-all.filter';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: AllExceptionsFilter,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and

> catch-all.filter.ts

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch()
export class AllExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();
    const request = ctx.getRequest();

    const status = exception instanceof HttpException ? exception.getStatus() : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    response.status(status).json({
      statusCode: status,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      path: request.url,
    });
  }
}
```

But if I try to send a req via postman with a malformed JSON the server crashes

any idea of how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is error occurs outside of the NestJS context (it uses the [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) library), you must handle it with an express middleware.

Try to implement one, which can detect, and handle these errors. For example:

```js
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err instanceof SyntaxError &&
    err.status >= 400 && err.status < 500 &&
    err.message.indexOf('JSON') !== -1) {
      res.status(400).send('send your own response here')
  }
  // ...
})
```